# Solr no content field = no highlighting

Tags: solr, highlight

I want to add highlighting to my search result from Solr. My problem is the query don't contain any content field.
Search seems to work, but I guess that when I create the index I need to tell Solr to stored the texts or something.

I am running Solr on Windows.

```
java -Dc=aceapps -Dauto=yes -Ddata=files -Drecursive=yes -Dfiletypes=pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar "\user\PowerBI"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer when we don't know your schema.xml or solrconfig.xml

Have a look at the Wiki for the standard highlighter:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Standard+Highlighter

Solr also comes with an example core called techproducts and in there is a good example of highlighting. Look at the request handler and highlighter in the solrconfig.xml and the fields it's being applied to in that example.

Comment: The only thing I have done is installed Solr and added some file to a index. So the the schema.xml and solrconfig.xml should be default. Is it possible to get highlight to work on word, excel, pdf..?

Comment: What core did you add the document to? techproducts? Or did you make a new one and add it to that?

Once a document is ingested by Solr it just gets converted to an inverse index of plain text, so all documents, whether they're word, excel, PDF, text, whatever end up as plain text in the index, so highlighting can work on anything that's indexed.

Comment: I created a new one.